# Nginx not matching server_name on https

Tags: nginx

my nginx configuration doesn´t match my https server and redirects to the server ip instead.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name www.example.de example.de;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    include snippets/example.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name www.example.de example.de;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm-butterbirne.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi.conf;
    }

    client_max_body_size 50m;
}
```

I have added default_server to it because some answers suggested that a default_server is necessary for matching.
Http is somehow fine but then it redirects to the machines ip instead. I will write 127.0.0.1 instead of the real ip

```
root@v22017043237047379:/etc/nginx# curl -I -L http://example.de
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Mon, 05 Jun 2017 08:30:09 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.example.de/

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Mon, 05 Jun 2017 08:30:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Pingback: https://127.0.0.1/xmlrpc.php
Location: https://127.0.0.1/
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name 'example.de' does not match target host name '127.0.0.1'
```

nginx is 1.10.3 and os Debian Jessi

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was something different. The error came from wordpress. It was configured to listen to an ip instead of the domain causing the wrong redirect.